# Eigenvalue-taking operator?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

$\newcommand{Tr}{\operatorname{Tr}}$
Is there a continuous map $(p,t) \mapsto \lambda(p,t)$ which, given a path $p: [0,1] \to M(2,\mathbb R)$ and a $t \in \mathbb [0,1]$, gives back an eigenvalue of $p(t)$? Additionally, I'd like it that if $p(a) = -p(b)$ for some $a, b \in [0,1]$, then $\lambda(p,a) = -\lambda(p,b)$.

A naive possibility would be $\lambda(p, t) = \frac{\Tr(p(t)) \pm \sqrt{\Tr(p(t))^2 - 4\det(p(t))} }2$, using the quadratic formula and the characteristic polynomial. But this has got $\pm$ in it, which is not a function. Changing $\pm$ into $+$, the image of the path $$p(t) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1-2t \\ 2t - 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is seen to violate the second condition: namely, $\lambda(p,0)=\lambda(p,1)=i$ when what's needed is $\lambda(p,0)=-\lambda(p,1)$.

This problem is unsolvable when $M(2, \mathbb R)$ is changed to $M(2, \mathbb C)$, as the existence of $\lambda(-,-)$ would violate the simple-connectivity of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: You switch between $\lambda$ and $L$.  It's also not clear what $\sqrt{\cdot}$ should mean in your proposed definition of $L$, as a well defined function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ (although I guess any naïve candidate is fine?).  What is the topology in which $\lambda$ is continuous?

Comment: Please clarify the domain of your function $\lambda$. Does it take in the whole path, or is it defined as $\lambda:M(2,\Bbb R)\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$? If it takes in the whole path, then we *really* need the topology you use on the space of paths.

Comment: @M.Winter I take your point. I only understand these concepts naively at the moment. It might be premature to be asking these questions if I don't know which topology to use for $M(2, \mathbb R)^{[0,1]}$, for instance. The motivation was to see if I could complete a proof of the lack of simple-connectivity of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$. And indeed $\lambda$ should take in the whole path, and the second condition should be in hindsight that $t \mapsto \lambda(p, t)$ is smooth whenever $p$ is smooth. But I'm even less sure how to solve that

Comment: By the way, the discriminant should be $\operatorname{Tr}(p(t))^2 - 4\det(p(t))$, not $\operatorname{Tr}(p(t))^2 + 4\det(p(t))$.

Comment: @LSpice Fixed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I originally gave a wrong candidate for an answer, but in fact no such path can exist (at least, assuming that your topologies are such that $t \mapsto \lambda(p, t)$ is continuous for all paths $p$).  Indeed, define $p : [0, 1] \to \operatorname M(2, \mathbb R)$ by
$$
p(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t) \\ \sin(\pi t) & -\cos(\pi t) \end{pmatrix}
$$
for all $t \in [0, 1]$.  Then $\lambda(p, t) \in \{\pm1\}$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$, but $\lambda(p, 1) = -\lambda(p, 0)$, which is impossible if $t \mapsto \lambda(p, t)$ is continuous.

EDIT:  I suspected from your mention of the simple connectedness of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$, and see definitely from [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331024/eigenvalue-taking-operator/331026#comment825407_331024), that you are interested in the non-simple connectedness of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$.  It may be that a particularly simple way to see this is to consider the [metaplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group), which is a non-split double cover of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$.  Notice that your original example can be adapted to give a *polynomial* path in $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ (not just in $\operatorname M(2, \mathbb R)$, or even just in $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$ as my original path was):
$$
t \mapsto p(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
t(1 - t) & 1 - t^2(6 - 4t) \\
-1 + t^2(6 - 4t) & 4t(1 - t)(3 - 2t)(1 + 2t)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Notice that the cover of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ implicit in your question, namely
$$
E \mathrel{:=} \{(g, \lambda) : \text{$g \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $g$}\},
$$
is a branched cover; it is a double cover only on the regular semisimple set (of elements with distinct eigenvalues).  Its restriction to the regular semisimple set is isomorphic (as a cover of the rss set) to the restriction there of the branched cover
$$
\{(g, B) : \text{$g \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ and $B$ is a Borel subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ containing $g$}\}
$$
(namely, associate $(g, \lambda)$ and $(g, B)$ if and only if the non-trivial eigenvalue of $\operatorname{Ad}(g)$ on $\operatorname{Lie}(B)$ is $\lambda^2$).  However, I think that the restriction is *not* isomorphic to the restriction of the metaplectic group.  Indeed, let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ be distinct elements of $\mathbb R$ satisfying $\lambda\mu = 1$.  Then any lift to $E$ of the path
$$
t \mapsto \operatorname{Int}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t) \\
-\sin(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix}
$$
projects, *via* $E \to \mathbb C$, to $\{\lambda, \mu\}$, hence is constantly $\lambda$ or constantly $\mu$; but, if I've done my computation properly, then
$$
\operatorname{Int}(w(t))\Bigl(\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix}, \sqrt\mu\Bigr),
$$
where $w(t) = \Bigl(\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t) \\
-\sin(\pi t) & \cos(\pi t)
\end{pmatrix}, \epsilon_t\Bigr)$, with $\epsilon_t(i) = e^{\pi i t/2}$, is a path in the restriction to the rss set of the metaplectic cover that connects the two pre-images of $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix}$.  (I'm using the description of points in the metaplectic group from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_group#Explicit_construction_for_n_=_1).)

Comment: The topologies are indeed the usual Euclidean topologies. The $\sqrt : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is really any continuous function such that $(\sqrt x)^2 = x$

Comment: It makes sense to speak of the continuity of a map $e$ like mine in the Euclidean topologies, but your map is defined on *paths*, which don't carry a Euclidean topology.  Probably something like the compact-open topology there is what you want.  Anyway, for any reasonable choice of topology on paths, at least the sort of composition I've suggested should be continuous.

Comment: @manonlaptop, sorry, this isn't continuous; consider its composition with $t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} t & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ at $t = 0$.  I'll think further.

Comment: @manonlaptop, in fact I now think that there is *no* such path, as evidenced by a small variant of your proposed example.  Please see the new edit.  Sorry for my mistake!

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question. But it's a nice example. My second condition should've been that if $p$ is smooth then $t \mapsto \lambda(p, t)$ should also be smooth. This is violated for $p(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi t) & -\sin(2\pi t) \\ \sin(2\pi t) & \cos(2\pi t) \end{pmatrix}$ and my naive definition of $\lambda$. After $t=0.5$, the trajectory of $t\mapsto\lambda(p,t)$ suddenly reverses. This is also why I used $L$ originally instead of $\lambda$, so I could talk about my example without confusing it with the imagined $\lambda$.I may reverse the edit that proposed the name change

Comment: @manandlaptop, I have edited my answer to reflect the connection with the metaplectic group and other kinds of covers of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$, which seems to be where your interest lies.

Comment: Shouldn't $t \mapsto \operatorname{Int}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t) \\
-\sin(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix}$ be $t \mapsto \operatorname{Int}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi t) & \sin(\pi t) \\
-\sin(\pi t) & \cos(\pi t)
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 \\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix}$ and shouldn't $\pi t$ be $2\pi t$? Thanks

Comment: @manandlaptop, yes on the first count ($\cos(\pi t)$ on the lower right, as in the next time I write the matrix).  On the second count, it definitely works either way on $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$.  (Note that the conjugating element at $t = 1$ is $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, which is central.)  I haven't re-done the computation, but I *think* you need to do it the way I did to wind up with a path in the metaplectic group between two *different* lifts of $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix}$.